# Send mails through localhost with Play Framework instead of Gmail SMTP?

Tags: email, playframework, gmail

I'm using the Play Framework for one of my projects and it is very important to send emails. Right now, this is done via Gmail using Google Apps for Business.

However, the problem is that Google blocks connections via SMTP to this specific account after some time without a login through the web interface. Maybe for spam reasons, I don't know. But this is a real problem for us, because I have a separate browser window running constantly in order to be able to send emails via the Play application using the SMTP protocol.

Is there any other possibility to send mails other than SMTP? I hate setting up mail servers and couldn't get mine running on localhost. So is there any e.g. sendmail alternative? Or would you recommend using another service than Google Apps for Business?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it help, but there is play plugin to send mail.

[This one](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer), for instance may solve your problem. But it is a very simple plug-in with no "attach file" functionnality. Follow [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/vMcUx0h5480) if you want to have informations about how to improve this plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Moebius! However, it seems like that this plugin required an SMTP connection, because the SMTP host is mandatory, right?

Comment: You know what, I simply stopped being a pussy and did it - I installed a local SMTP server. Even tough it took an hour to set it up correctly, it really works now. I feel like a man.

Comment: Great ! I couldn't had help you go further anyway.